# how to transform/group this kind of raw json data into hierarchy strucutre

Tags: javascript, json

I have a set of room data in json, each room data includes which site, building and floor it resides in.

The data examples are like

```
[
{
  'site':'liverpool', 'building':'building a', 'floor':'0', 'room':'room a'
},
{
  'site':'liverpool', 'building':'building a', 'floor':'1', 'room':'room b' 
},
{
  'site':'liverpool', 'building':'building b', 'floor':'0', 'room':'room a' 
}
............
]
```

now I using javascript to break down this data set into a hierarchy structure, such as

```
{
    'site':[
        {
            'name':'liverpool',
            'buildings':[
                {
                    'name':'building a',
                    'floors':[
                     {
                         'name':0,
                         'rooms':['room a', 'room b']
                     }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

for me, it is still very hard to transform the raw data into the wanted structure, could someone instruct me how to do it?

I have tried with underscore, but only achieved with one hierarchy.

```
 var groups = _.groupBy(data,function(room){
                return (room.site+","+room.building+","+room.floor);        
            })
```

Comment: that second json doesn't look quite good.

Comment: You can try [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) `_.groupBy` method.

Comment: Hi, Fizer, I have tried the _.groupBy methods, but all I can do is the one level hierarchy. see my updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `var data` is your JSON:

```
var sites = [];

for(var i=0,l=data.length;i<l;i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var site = false;
    var building = false;
    var floor = false;

//  search for existing site
    for(var j=0,k=sites.length;j<k;j++) {
        if(sites[j].name == row.site) {
            site = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(site === false) {
        site = sites.length;
        sites[site] = {
            name: row.site,
            buildings: []
        };
    }

//  search for existing building
    for(var j=0,k=sites[site].buildings.length;j<k;j++) {
        if(sites[site].buildings[j].name == row.building) {
            building = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(building === false) {
        building = sites[site].buildings.length;
        sites[site].buildings[building] = {
            name: row.building,
            floors: []
        };
    }

//  search for existing floor
    for(var j=0,k=sites[site].buildings[building].floors.length;j<k;j++) {
        if(sites[site].buildings[building].floors[j] == row.floor) {
            floor = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(floor === false) {
        floor = sites[site].buildings[building].floors.length;
        sites[site].buildings[building].floors[floor] = row.floor;
    }
}
```

**Resulting Structure:**

```
var sites = [
    {
        "name":"liverpool",
        "buildings":[
            {
                "name":"building a",
                "floors":[
                    "0",
                    "1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"building b",
                "floors":[
                    "0"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

**Use it:**

```
var liverpool = sites[0];
var building_b = liverpool.buildings[1];
```

There are probably better ways of doing it though.